# whether a nonce is required for get type and get_query_var?

Tags: wp-query, forms, security, nonce

I have a front form that allows filtering. I think I need a nonce but I am not sure to use it or not.
I use the `get_query_var` method to modify the main query. It uses a get method.

1. whether a nonce is used for `get` methods?
2. How to implement nonce with `get_query_var`

```
<form action="" method="get">
<?php wp_nonce_field('my_delete_action'); ?>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value=" <?php echo $id; ?> " />
<input type="text" name="rec_name" value=" <?php echo $name; ?> " />
<input type="submit" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

Comment: Is this form accessible to anonymous users? If so, a nonce is useless.

Comment: @fuxia yes it is for all the users. It's a front end filtering form. So hope all good there.

Comment: Nonces are based on the user id. So you'd get the same nonce for everyone, because their id is 0.